# Bash 4, expansion and putting to lowercase

Tags: bash

I see that in Bash > 4.0 variable expansion is used to lowercase a variable. For example

```
echo ${variable,,}
```

Reading the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) I really don't get why the shell is converting the string to lowercase.

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer. When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between x and y, inclusive. Supplied integers may be prefixed with ‘0’ to force each term to have the same width. When either x or y begins with a zero, the shell attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding where necessary. When characters are supplied, the expression expands to each character lexicographically between x and y, inclusive, using the default C locale. Note that both x and y must be of the same type. When the increment is supplied, it is used as the difference between each term. The default increment is 1 or -1 as appropriate.

Why is the variable converted to lowercase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading the wrong section of the documentation; look at [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead.

> `${parameter^pattern}`
>
> `${parameter^^pattern}`
>
> `${parameter,pattern}`
>
> `${parameter,,pattern}`
>
> This expansion modifies the case of alphabetic characters in `parameter`. The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Each character in the expanded value of `parameter` is tested against `pattern`, and, if it matches the pattern, its case is converted. The pattern should not attempt to match more than one character. The ‘^’ operator converts lowercase letters matching pattern to uppercase; the ‘,’ operator converts matching uppercase letters to lowercase. The ‘^^’ and ‘,,’ expansions convert each matched character in the expanded value; the ‘^’ and ‘,’ expansions match and convert only the first character in the expanded value. If `pattern` is omitted, it is treated like a ‘?’, which matches every character. If `parameter` is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the case modification operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If `parameter` is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the case modification operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 4):

You are quoting the part for "Brace Expansion", A "Brace expansion" does not start with a `$`.

You should execute this command:

```
LESS=+/'\{parameter\^pattern\}' man bash
```

To find the part of "case modification" that start with a `$` (`${ ^^ }`).

Comment: The value you're assigning to `LESS` looked familiar but when I ran it I got a blank screen and a bunch of `unsupported control character: 0x7` after hitting `q`. I was confused at first but after a while I figured out that this one works for me: `LESS=+/'\{parameter\/pattern\/string\}' man bash` (because that's the pattern in my manpages). It's in the "Parameter Expansion". Is that the right section? I also found out that `less` is the default manpager and setting `LESS` to a less's search string before invoking `less` jumps to that pattern in `man pages`. Neat.